# Is there a C/C++ compiler/linker which is embedable directly in a C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

The idea is to generate C/C++ code at run-time, compile it to a shared object, and load that shared object in the current process.

I know it could be done by using an existing compiler installation on the host platform (GCC or MSVC), but in a practical scenario the client don't necessary have such installation. So the idea is to statically link with such compiler and linker.

For example in Java, you can compile .java classes directly from java code. It can be used to generate automatically a Buisness Objects from a database schema.

Comment: You'd have to embed the entire standard library too, so I'm gonna take a wild guess and say 'no'.

Comment: Doesn't the "invoke java compiler from java program" require a JDK on the computer running the program? Anyway, it might be possible but it certainly won't be easy or cheap w.r.t. memory.

Comment: Why don't you just deliver your programm with a suitable compiler? E.g. lcc?

Comment: @delnan, err he's asking for C++..

Comment: @halfdan: I was responding to the last paragraph.

Comment: @halfdan Looks like a missing tag. I see C and C++ in his question

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do this with the c-language front end ([clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)) to [llvm](http://llvm.org). The [static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) built on top of clang may give you some ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: I hope you mean Clang. LLVM != Clang.

Comment: @delnan, semantically true, and I did change my answer. However, I thought the OP would be able to determine that he needed to use  clang, but I was not sure how much of the underlying LLVM libraries would be required. Therefor, I thought it more useful to suggest LLVM, as a whole, then clang itself.

Comment: @rcollyer: he would need both CLang and LLVM, CLang is the C++ front-end and LLVM generates the code.

Comment: CLang looks definitively embeddable since it is a library, but what about llvm? Is it embeddable too?

Comment: llvm is the suite of libraries clang is built upon, so I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1):

There is tinyC: http://bellard.org/tcc/.  I know nothing similar for C++.

Answer (score 1):

Google 'c interpreter embed' and you'll get as a first hits

- http://www.softintegration.com/ (embeddable C/C++ interpreter)

  - review/article [here](http://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-1042)
- http://code.google.com/p/picoc/ (C only?)

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, such thing can not be done for c or c++. You have to start a new process (in which you execute a compiler), and requires a compiler to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna hacve a look at [the crack language](https://code.google.com/p/crack-language/), based on llvm, it's in early phase but seems quite near from what you try to achieve.