# Compile a .cpp file to an EXE inside of a program (EXE file)

Tags: c++, compilation, exe

I want to make a program ([EXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE) file) that will take the user defined settings and make a custom (EXE) file for the user inside of the previously mentioned program (EXE). Is there like a portable [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) or something?

Please be as detailed as possible. I am not really sure where to start with this one.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677493/is-there-a-c-c-compiler-linker-which-is-embedable-directly-in-a-c-c-program/5677638#5677638

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler itself is just another program which reads some input (source code) and writes some output (object code, or executable if it runs the linker too). You can use something like the `system()` call to execute a compiler, for example with gcc:

```
system("g++ -o test test.cpp");
```

That will run the compiler (`g++`), telling it to create an output file with a specific name (`-o test`) using the named source file (`test.cpp`).

Comment: i tried this and it works in my codeblock project. but as soon as I run the .exe outside of codeblocks it give me error: g++ is not recognized as an internal or external

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for this is to use an [embedded resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_%28Windows%29) - then use e.g. [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648030%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and related functions to modify a precreated EXE file. The MSDN overview of [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468901%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) contains the information you need to add a `RT_RCDATA` block to your EXE, retrieve its contents run-time, and modify its contents from another program.