# "undefined reference to" using 'g++' to compile a C++ program

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-reference

I can't seem to get the errors to go away. The errors are below. I have looked on Google Search and still I can't figure it out. It is not like I am new to C++, but I have not fooled around with it in a while.

**The weird thing is it worked with g++ on Windows...**

Errors using:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

Output:

> /tmp/ccJL2ZHE.o: In function `main': \ main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to` Help::Help()' 
> main.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `Help::sayName()' \ main.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to` Help::~Help()' 
> main.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `Help::~Help()' 
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

#### File *main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Help.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {

    Help h;
    h.sayName();

    // ***

    // ***

    // ***
    return 0;

}
```

#### File *Help.h*

```
#ifndef HELP_H
#define HELP_H

class Help {
    public:
        Help();
        ~Help();
        void sayName();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // HELP_H
```

#### File *Help.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Help.h"

using namespace std;

Help::Help() { // Constructor
}

Help::~Help() { // Destructor
}

void Help::sayName() {
    cout << "            ***************" << endl;
    cout << "   ************************************" << endl;
    cout << "              ************" << endl;
    cout << "         *********************" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Re *"The weird thing is it worked with g++ on Windows..."*: What platform was this tried on? Did it work in the past on Windows, but now it doesn't work on Windows? Or was this tried on something else than Windows, like Linux? The shell prompt suggests [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) or [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) on Windows or perhaps Linux.

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 8 years ago"*. We may never know. [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689437/compile-cpp-file-to-exe-inside-of-programexe) 4 months prior suggests the platform of choice could be Windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

```
g++ main.cpp Help.cpp
```

You have to tell the compiler all the files that you want it to compile, not just the first one.

Answer (score 8):

You should add help.o to your g++ line:

```
g++ -c help.cpp -o help.o
g++ help.o main.cpp
```

By splitting it to two lines you can save compilation time (in case of larger projects), because you can compile `help.cpp` only when it was changed. `make` and `Makefile` used well will save you a lot of headache:

```
#Makefile
all: main

main: help main.cpp
    g++ -o main help.o main.cpp

help: help.cpp
    g++ -c -o help.o help.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Linux [Lubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) distribution and it was creating the problem for my constructor and destructor. It was not recognizing them.

Actually, this goes off if you just **compile all of  the three files together.** So, once you saved all your files, just do this:

```
g++ main.cpp Help.h Help.cpp
./a.out
```

*./a.out* is the executable file for the Linux. Sorry, but I don't know about the Windows. And your program would run smoothly.