# Undefined Reference? But I've already implemented the function

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, linker-errors

**display.h**

```
#ifndef PRO_DISPLAY_H
#define PRO_DISPLAY_H

/** Initializes the display **/
int pro_display_init(void);

#endif /* PRO_DISPLAY_H */
```

**display.c**

```
#include "main.h"

static int height_ = 300;
static int width_ = 300;
static int bpp_ = 16;

static SDL_Surface* screen_ = NULL;

int pro_display_init(void)
{
    screen_ = SDL_SetVideoMode(width_, height_, bpp_, SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    if (!screen_)
    {
        pro_sdl_error("Video initialization failed.");
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**main.h**

```
#ifndef PRO_MAIN_H
#define PRO_MAIN_H

// standard headers
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// conditional headers
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#endif

// our own headers
#include "scripter.h"
#include "ttf_util.h"
#include "events.h"
#include "display.h"

// some macros
#define pro_error(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#define pro_sdl_error(x) fprintf(stderr, "%s. \n=> %s\n", x, SDL_GetError())
#define pro_ttf_error(x) fprintf(stderr, "%s. \n=> %s\n", x, TTF_GetError())

#endif /* PRO_MAIN_H */
```

** main.c**

```
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pro_display_init();
    return 0;
}
```

The Error:

```
main.c|5|undefined reference to `pro_display_init()'|
```

Checked the build process. Made sure I was adding "display.c" to gcc's input files. I'm at my wit's end. Why the error?

Comment: are the header files in the same directory of the source files? If not, did you include the header file directory?

Comment: @BinyaminSharet yes. they are in the same directory as the source files.

Comment: Your prototype and function both implement a returned int, your use of pro_display_init() does not. Perhaps that's the issue...

Comment: Edit your question and add the command you're using to compile the thing.

Comment: @cnicutar I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE.

Comment: You're not linking in the object file/library containing the symbol.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker : Are you sure that your file isn't called "main.cpp" ?

Comment: Then you've a long path before becoming "intermediate".

Comment: @Kirilenko no. definitely main.c . Here, I uploaded [the project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/51527234/SDL_platformer.zip).

Comment: @cnicutar [happy now](http://stackoverflow.com/users/753341/apprenticehacker)?

Comment: I was joking, I seriously hope I did not offend you. I thoroughly regret my snarky comment :-(

Comment: @cnicutar lol. I don't get offended that easily. I'm joking too. :D

Comment: Okay :-) I'm not very familiar with `CB` but I think it doesn't know how to link your object files. Try (temporarily) a makefile ?

Comment: try compiling from command line first..see if that works.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["undefined reference to" in G++ Cpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978241/undefined-reference-to-in-g-cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display.c and main.c are compiled into their own "translation unit". What happens is that when trying to resolve symbols name (i.e. looking for `pro_display_init`), the C compiler thinks it's compiling a standalone .c unit. The proper way to go is to compile them separately and then link them, e.g.

```
gcc -c display.c # creates display.o
gcc main.c display.o # compiles main.o and then link with display.o
```

Of course, you'll be creating/reusing a Makefile soon that lets you define rules for all this.

Comment: so it means one must always compile a single .c file at once?

Comment: It could be that your latest flavour of GCC is smart enough to do "gcc -c display.c ; gcc main.c display.o" when you say "gcc main.c display.c", but to be honest, I wouldn't rely on that. One thing is certain: it won't guess that display.c should be compiled and linked just because you #include "display.h" ... and #include "display.c" is significantly different and considered bad practice by most of us.

Comment: ok, I just compiled this using `gcc display.c main.c` with gcc under MacOS with no problem (of course I removed all unrelated stuff first).

Answer (score 0):

I think, #include "main.h" or #include "display.h" (in main.h) "finds" the wrong include file. Check you include_path variable.