# undefined reference to base constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, undefined-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“undefined reference to” in G++ Cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978241/undefined-reference-to-in-g-cpp)

I have this header

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

class TEST
{
public :
    TEST();
};


#endif /* TEST_H_ */
```

and this header

```
#ifndef TESTS_H_
#define TESTS_H_
#include "TEST.h"

class TESTS : public TEST
{
public :
    TESTS();
};


#endif /* TESTS_H_ */
```

I implemented those header like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "TEST.h"
TEST:: TEST()
{
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

and this:

```
#include "TESTS.h"

TESTS :: TESTS() : TEST()
{
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

and I get the follwing error:

/tmp/cc4jN1HN.o: In function `TESTS::TESTS()':
TESTS.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to`TEST::TEST()'

Why is it ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You can't ask us what you're doing wrong if you don't tell us what you're *trying* to do! And it's far from clear: Why do you have two `main` functions?! A program can only have one. Is this supposed to be two programs or one program?

Answer (score 6):

This is a linker error. You're probably not compiling and linking all the required files. It should be e.g.:

```
$ g++ -Wall TEST.cpp TESTS.cpp -o TEST
```

You also need to get rid of one of the main() functions.

Comment: Thank you both !!! It help me . and I delete one of the main.

Answer (score 1):

If this is supposed to be one program, it can only have one `main` function. If this is supposed to be two programs, then the one with `TESTS::TESTS` in it also needs the constructor for `TEST`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your two .cpp files are named TEST.cpp and TESTS.cpp, I'm guessing you're just compiling the first one, such as with

```
g++ TESTS.cpp
```

but you need to compile them both together, such as with

```
g++ TEST.cpp TESTS.cpp
```

otherwise, TESTS.cpp won't be able to find the code defined in TEST.cpp when it's compiling.