# What is the syntax for object instantiation in C++?

Tags: c++

when I compile the following c++ code:

```
#include "ConstantList.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

ConstantList* cl = new ConstantList();

//do something with cl

delete cl;
cl = NULL;

return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives me the error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "ConstantList::~ConstantList()", referenced from:
      _main in ccNfeeDU.o
  "ConstantList::ConstantList()", referenced from:
      _main in ccNfeeDU.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I not getting the syntax right for instantiating an object?
My ConstantList.h file looks like this:

```
#ifndef ConstantList_h
#define ConstantList_h

#include <string>
#include "Token.h"


using namespace std;

class ConstantListTail;

class ConstantList {
public:
    ConstantList();
    ~ConstantList();

    std::string toString();

    void push_back(Token*);
    void push_back(ConstantListTail*);

private:
    Token* termString;
    ConstantListTail* constantListTail;
};



#endif
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["undefined reference to" in G++ Cpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978241/undefined-reference-to-in-g-cpp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, because you are getting a linker error, not a compiler error. This error means that you are compiling your `main` without the source of the `ConstantList.cpp`, or linking without a reference to `ConstantList.o`

Compiling with this command should fix the error:

```
g++ collect2.cpp ConstantList.cpp
```

(I am assuming that the file with your `main` function is called `collect2.cpp`).

Comment: Thanks--Initially I compiled my whole project (72 .cpp and .h files) with g++ *.cpp. No compiler errors. Then I tried running it. All it gave me was "Bus error" on a Mac and "Cannot execute binary file" on linux. I researched and it was suggested that this was due to invalid memory accesses. So I started putting all my pointers under scrutiny. After some troubleshooting I tried compiling independently each file to see if my syntax with pointers was right. Wasn't sure if the pointer syntax or object instantiation or something else was the cause of that problem. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

"undefined symbol" means you have declared the identifier (in this case the destructor), and it's used, but as far as the linker knows you have not defined it

add a definition somewhere, and make sure the compiled version is in one of the files the linker links

---

re "syntax for instantiation", unfortunately there is no dedicated syntax for that in C++

instead the functional cast notation is used for constructor invocations

perhaps the closest you get to a pure instantiation syntax is the `new` expression

---

re

```
using namespace std;
```

in a header file: **don't**.

for example, the standard library defines something called `distance`. what are the chances that some code that includes the header will have its own `distance`, and get a name collision? much higher than zero.

this doesn't mean you should never have `using namespace std;` in a header file, but you should never have it in the global namespace in a header file. and for other namespaces, be very aware of what that does, namely offering all the standard library names as part of also that namespace.

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning C++ coming from a java background. I was desperate trying to get this code to just compile and was troubleshooting with the namespace. I forgot to remove it from the header file.