# I am very new to C++ and I am trying to make a hit-counter. I am stuck building the class, and am getting some compiler errors

Tags: c++, counter

This is what I have so far for the class file and I am not really sure what the next step to take it. Hit should increase the value by 1, and reset should set it back to 0. The main function in the .cpp file should test its functionality with the manual hit and set commands. Any help or advice with how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Header file WebCounter.h:

```
#include<iostream>
  class WebCounter {
    private:
      int value;
      value=0;
    public:
      void set(int value);
      void reset();
      void hit();
      int get();
};
```

Main function to test the Counter

```
   #include"WebCounter.h"
   #include<iostream>

  using namespace std;

  int main() {

    WebCounter hitcount;
    hitcount.reset();
    cout << hitcount.get() << endl;

    int value;

    value=hitcount.get();
    cout << value << endl;
    hitcount.hit();
    hitcount.hit();
    hitcount.hit();
    hitcount.hit();
    cout << hitcount.get() << endl;
    hitcount.set(77);
    cout << hitcount.get() << endl;
    hitcount.set(89);

    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I get when compiling the .cpp file

```
g++ WebCounter.cpp
/tmp/cce7bLn5.o: In function `main':
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `WebCounter::reset()'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `WebCounter::get()'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `WebCounter::get()'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `WebCounter::hit()'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `WebCounter::hit()'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `WebCounter::hit()'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `WebCounter::hit()'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `WebCounter::get()'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `WebCounter::set(int)'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `WebCounter::get()'
WebCounter.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `WebCounter::set(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You have not defined any of the functions. Next step is to define every function and implement their logic.

Comment: Did you implement these functions in WebCounter.cpp and compile/link it properly?

Comment: How did `value=0;` in the class definition get past the compiler?

Comment: I just added that right before posting and hadn't tried compiling again. The intent was to have the starting value at 0. Based on your comment I guess that is something I shouldn't have done.

Comment: @user1359790, That's what a constructor does, or, in C++11, you could just say `int value{};` right in the class to avoid having to make a constructor in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["undefined reference to" in G++ Cpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978241/undefined-reference-to-in-g-cpp)

Answer (score 0):

Come up with WebCounter.cpp that will have the implementation for all the functions (get, hit, set, etc.) that you've declare in WebCounter.h. Then try compiling it. Once it gets compiled successfully, try compiling the .cpp that has the main method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide implementations for:

```
  void WebCounter::set(int value);
  void WebCounter::reset();
  void WebCounter::hit();
  int WebCounter::get();
```