# undefined reference to constructor in C++

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I am creating a constructor of class Level as follows but b I am getting an error message that:

```
D:\downloads\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4\armadillo\proj.android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:43: undefined reference to `Levels::Levels()'
D:\downloads\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4\armadillo\proj.android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:44: undefined reference to `Levels::getCachedDataFromFile(std::string)'
```

Code:

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
  if ( !CCLayer::init() )
  {
    return false;
  }
  _levels = new Levels();
  _levels->getCachedDataFromFile("\mnt\sdcard\levels.json");
  return true;
}
```

I am calling this method in constructor in HelloWorld.cpp file. I have included Levels.h file in HelloWorld.h which I included in HelloWorld.cpp.

I'll be grateful if any one can help me out as I am beginner to cpp.

I have included the method and constructor in header file, you can check it in following code:

```
#include "Box2d.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"

using namespace cocos2d;

#ifndef LEVELS_H_
#define LEVELS_H_

class Levels: public b2ContactListener {

public:

Levels();
~Levels();

void BeginContact(b2Contact *contact);
void EndContact(b2Contact *contact);
void preSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold);
void postSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse);
void getCachedDataFromFile(string filePath);


private:

//  const string LEVEL_FILE_NAME = "levels.json";

};

#endif /* LEVELS_H_ */
```

Level.cpp

```
#include "Levels.h"
#include <android/log.h>


#define  LOG_TAG    "levels"
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

Levels::Levels() {

}

Levels::~Levels() {

}

void Levels::BeginContact(b2Contact *contact) {

}

void Levels::EndContact(b2Contact *contact) {

}

void Levels::getCachedDataFromFile(string filePath) {
unsigned long filesize = 0;
unsigned char* fileData = NULL;
std::string content, fullPath;
int i =1;
fullPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()-    >       fullPathFromRelativePath(filePath.c_str());

fileData = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(fullPath.c_str(),
        "r", &filesize);
content.append((char*) fileData);
LOGD(content.c_str());
 // if (languagesDocument.Parse < 0 > (content.c_str()).HasParseError()) {
 //     LOGD(languagesDocument.GetParseError());
 ////       CCLog(languagesDocument.GetParseError());
//  }
```

//   return NULL;
    }

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#OpenCV
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include ../../../projects/android-opencv/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp
#Required for android log from jni code
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

#Add path to OpenCV's header files
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes     \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/Box2d \
../../../projects/android-opencv/sdk/native/jni/include/

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static          c cocos_extension_static box2d_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) \
$(call import-module,cocos2dx) \
$(call import-module,extensions) \ 
$(call import-module,Box2D)
```

Comment: Add the declaration of `getCachedDataFromFile` from `Level.h`. The current information is not enough

Comment: Include the header where Levels is defined. And you're not creating a constructor of Levels.

Comment: Are you compiling/linking Level.cpp as well as including its header?

Comment: This looks like a linker error. Are you linking both `HellowWorld.cpp` and `Level.cpp` into your program?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["undefined reference to" in G++ Cpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978241/undefined-reference-to-in-g-cpp)

Comment: I have added the header file.

Comment: You do have a method `Levels::Levels()` defined (not just declared in the.hpp file), do you?

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the constructor? In Levels.cpp add this:

```
Levels::Levels()
{
    // constructor code here …
}
```

Likewise with the destructor:

```
Levels::~Levels()
{
    // destructor code here …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `Levels.cpp` to the list of src files in your Android.mk. It should be:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/Levels.cpp
```

Any file with classes that you create later should be added to the list as well.