# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 when accessing function in another class

Tags: c++, macos, class, undefined-symbol

I have a `Class` named `MyClass` and I have a function that is defined as public, I'm trying to call this function from another file that has a `main` function `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

**MyClass.h:**

```
 class MyClass:
 {
   public:
       MyClass();
       ~MyClass();
       PerformOperation(int*, int);
  }
```

**MyClass.c**

```
void MyClass::PerformOperation(int* myarr, int number)
{
   //Do something
 }
```

**myMainprog.c**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 MyClass obj;
 int* myArr = {1,4,7,0,2};
 int num    = 5;
 obj->(myArr, num);
 }
```

When I compile my code I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
MyClass::PerformOperation(int* myarr, int number), referenced from: _main in   ccUbOgEv.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I'm running my code on `OSX 10.9.4` using `g++`.

And my problem is not that I did not specify all the files as it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978241/undefined-reference-to-in-g-cpp).

The code works perfectly on linux.

Comment: **Which** symbols are not found?

Comment: @BoPersson I edit my question

Comment: There are no classes in C.

Comment: @Lily - Ok, I have changed this back to C++ and vote to reopen.

Comment: @immibis I'm running it using g++ as c++ code