# how to modify the code in a exe file after an update

Tags: c++, qt, exe

I'm having a complete program, but now, I want it to be able to be updated. So I would like to change the "code" in the executable by the new code without having to recompile it.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do, I coding in C++ in Qt Creator.

Thanks for any advise/clue

Comment: Without having to recompile what exactly? Obviously you cannot execute your new code (either inside the old or a new executable) unless you compile it first.

Comment: I meant...I would like that : my program notice there is an update, so it downloads it, change the code in the exe that is modified in the update and then be launch the program right after ready to use

Comment: And how would that be better than simply downloading a new exe and copying it over the old?

Comment: I can do this? I mean whatever platform I use I can simply replace the old exe by the new one?

Comment: That's how copying files works. The catch is that you cannot make the exe replace itself while it is running, so you need another exe to replace the first. Which is why all programs that auto-update have a separate "updater" component.

Comment: alright thanks it's now a lot more clear to me...and also seem easier than I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly what Jon told me : simply replace the old exe by the new one

Answer (score 3):

C++ can't do this. With QT, you could have a javascript implementation of the code you want changed and update that.

Comment: so...to be able to do that, I must know exactly which part of the code can be modified and code this part in JavaScript?!?!

Comment: @HugoCardin: Yes, or some other non-compiled language.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that this answer (and the comment above) is technically correct, but IMHO it is also not only useless to the OP but even *misleading*.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't technically do this in C++ without recompiling, if you don't want to rewrite in another programming language, you *could* write a small helper program that (while the original program is not running) recompiles the first program.

If you really wanted to do this (it's not hard at all) I'd look into [GNU g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/).
If you're using Windows, you'll probably want [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (which I believe comes with g++ installed). Both are free/open source and fall under the GNU GPL (something you need to look at if you are planning on *selling* your program. However, you're free to give it away)

Basically you could run your program, call another program before closing, and have that program act as a script to call g++ to re-compile your code. I've done this before, but for faster debugging rather than actually releasing a program that works that way.

Comment: If you decide to go this route... [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689437/compile-cpp-file-to-exe-inside-of-programexe) a SO question involving just that

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this answers your needs, but did you look into the ClickOnce platform? Although the code still gets recompiled on your server the client executable gets updated via ClickOnce.

Comment: that would have a possibility but it seems like working only on windows...I need to make it work on any system...thanks!